# regular expression for tree string manipulation

Tags: python, regex, string, expression

I have following string:

```
(S{4077..4157} (IN{4077..4081} '(,{4157..4158} ,{4157..4158}) (S{4159..4288} (IN{4159..4163} that{4159..4163})'
```

I want to extract `S{4077..4157}` and `,{4157..4158}) (S{4159..4288}` pattern:

I tried this regex:

```
match = re.compile( r',([{[0-9]+..[0-9}]+[)])*[\s]*[(SBAR{][{0-9]+..[0-9}]', re.M|re.I)

for tr in trees:
    #tr.draw()
    tr1=str(tr)

    matchObj =  match.findall(s)
    if matchObj:
        print ("match : ", matchObj)
    else:
        print ("No match!!")
```

Comment: ... and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: is there any logic? Why you want to extract those three only?

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.compile( r'\((S\{\d+..\d+})\s+\(\w+\{\d+..\d+\}\s+'\((,\{\d+..\d+\})\s+,\{\d+..\d+\}\)\s*\((S\{\d+..\d+\})', re.M|re.I)

for tr in trees:
    #tr.draw()
    tr1=str(tr)

    matchObj =  match.findall(s)
    if matchObj:
        print math.group(1)
        print match.group(2)
        print match.group(3)
    else:
        print ("No match!!")
```